# How to Weigh in Fake Coin Algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, math, bit-manipulation

I am trying to develop the C++ code for the Fake Coin Problem. I am using a binary array n long filled with 1s and a random 0 to represent the fake coin. When I divide the array in 2 halves to compare weights how do I go about determining the weight of each side?

I can count the number of 1s in each array easily enough but that would be a linear run time. The overall algorithm should be sub linear.

Is there a way to determine the weight of each array in constant time?

Disclosure: this is a school assignment so hopefully you can give a hint without giving the full answer.

Comment: This is more a math problem than a software problem. You are better off asking at a math QA.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decision-trees-fake-coin-puzzle/ this explain your problem. It looks like the optimal solution is log3(N) which is sub-linear

Comment: You have the wrong data structure. Your data structure should have a sectret number - the id of the fake coin, that is all. Then you could answer the queries a la "`coin_set1`  heavier than `coin_set2`?" in O(1).

Answer (score 1):

As a student I would stick to this, since you count the number of 1s in every *half*, and you are using effectively this approach:

> Decrease-and-Conquer

As a result you are actually weighing O(log<sub>2</sub> n) times, which makes the algorithm sublinear.

My point is that what will optimize the algorithm is the number of weighings you are performing and their effective space (half versus total).

Read more in this CS [session](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~wallingf/teaching/cs3530/sessions/session17.html), where it is suggested that if you split at 3, you could do better and achieve an O(log<sub>3</sub> n). However, if you are new to this, the split in half is just fine for now! =)

---

In case you want to play around with some code, you could use [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/), which provides [count()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/count/), that returns the number of 1s in the bitset.

Answer (score 0):

> I can count the number of 1s in each array easily enough but that would be a linear run time. The overall algorithm should be sub linear.

I think you are mistaken here. The **whole algorithm can not** possibly **be sub-linear** and it is easy to see why: to read each coin at least ones you need linear time because there is obviously linear number of coins in number of coins. And it is obvious that you can't find the fake coin without reading each coin at least once. (More strictly you are required to read all coins but one at least once but that is still linear.)

So what other answers and comments suggest is that you need sub-linear number of times you *weigh* coins and I tend to agree with that.

If you still want to perform comparisons (i.e. sums over ranges)  faster there is a data-structure called [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) which allows you to calculate sub-range sums in logarithmic time but still requires linear time for construction. Note however that I think that using it for your tasks is an overkill both in terms of complexity (it is probably more advanced than your current level) and in terms of performance bonus (it makes sense to use it only if you are going to have many `range` queries run over your array AND you are going to change your array).

Please also note that the second paragraph of the wiki article suggest a simple algorithm that takes only linear time for initialization and then computes prefix sums (and thus range-sums) in constant time: just create one more array with prefix sums of your coins (or even update the original one in-place if you don't need it anymore). Obviously `RangeSum(a,b) = PrefixSum(b) - PrefixSum(a-1)` (where `PrefixSum(-1)` is 0). It might make sense to implement this one if you want to show off, but still there will be no performance bonus in terms of Big-O.